# Counts the table values using inner join in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

1. `application_info`
2. `application_movement`

When user will apply for the job, then details will inserted into the `application_info` table and HR activities like hold candidate, decline, shortlist and schedule will updated in the `application_movement` table.

`application_info`:

```
applicationId    appliedjobID    emailID               status
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     1                3          usercandi@gmail.com   pending
     2                9          user2@gmail.com       pending
     3                2          user3@gmail.com       pending
```

`applicaiton_movement`:

```
ApplicationId  Fromstatus  toStatus         movementemailID
--------------------------------------------------------
1                pending      hold             hr@gmail.com
1                hold        **decline**       hr@gmail.com
2                pending      shortlist        hr1@gmail.com
2                shortlist   **scheduled**     hr1@gmail.com
3                pending     **scheduled**     hr@gmail.com
```

HR will do hold, decline, shortlist and scheduled, I need counts of hr@gmail.com and hr1@gmail.com (how many activities did by her counts like hold, decline, shortlist and a scheduled interview from `tostatus` column)

In `application_movement`, `ApplicationID` are two or more times.. So need a count of the last updated `tostatus` count only..

```
  i.e   hr@gmail.com     decline(1)   scheduled(1)  

        hr1@gmail.com    scheduled(1)
```

Just need select query base on two tables of `applicationId` fetch the counts.

Comment: Does `application_movement` table have a `DATETIME` column or something else based on what we can decide "last" movement?

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct(toStatus)))  ,toStatus         , movementemailID
 where tostatus in ('decline' , 'shortlist' , 'scheduled')
group by toStatus         , movementemailID
```

Hope it will suffice your requirement,  it will give you output like this and then you can put order by on toStatus or movementemailID as per your preference.

```
Count            toStatus         movementemailID
--------------------------------------------------------
1                decline       hr@gmail.com
1                 shortlist        hr1@gmail.com
1                scheduled     hr1@gmail.com
1                scheduled     hr@gmail.com
```

Comment: **decline** ,**scheduled** and **scheduled**  these count only should display by according to hr.

Comment: i need result like that... i.e   hr@gmail.com :    decline(1)   scheduled(1)  

        hr1@gmail.com:    scheduled(1)

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to get that, lets wait someone will come up this the answer. Couldn't you do this appending the part from where you are calling query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) for getting count of final movements in the own column

```
SELECT movementemailID
, [**decline**]
, [**scheduled**]
FROM (SELECT movementemailID, applicationId, tostatus
     FROM applicaiton_movement
     WHERE tostatus IN ('**decline**', '**scheduled**')) AS app_mov
PIVOT (COUNT(applicationId)
      FOR tostatus IN ([**decline**]
                      , [**scheduled**])
      ) AS info
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7411e/25)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Select Count(*) as numberOfHolds from applicaiton_movement Where movementemailID = hr@gmail.com and toStatus = 'hold'
```

If so, you could easily write a procedure that counts all status tags applied by all users and returns it in this format.

```
CountHold  | CountDecline |    movementemailID
--------------------------------------------------------
   1       |        2     |       me@yahoo.com
   3       |        3     |       them@xbc.com
   2       |       8000   |       hr1@gmail.com
   1       |        4     |       hr@gmail.com
```

Like this:
create the function,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CountDeclines]
(
    @user nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS @result int

AS
BEGIN
    Select @result = Count(*)  from applicaiton_movement    Where movementemailID = @user and toStatus = '**decline**'
END
```

Now call the function

```
Select CountDecliens(movementemailID) as [countdeclines], movementemailID from applicaiton_movement
```